# Issue about using pip3 on macOS Catalina default shell zsh

Tags: python, pip, zsh, macos-catalina

I have updated my MacOS to Catalina, and trying using `zsh` instead of `bash`.

However, when I wanna install some python libraries like numpy with `pip3 install numpy`, it shows error `pip3: error: can't exec '/usr/local/bin/pip3' (errno=No such file or directory)`

Could somebody help me fix this issue and tell me some guidance on using `zsh` on MacOS? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `brew reinstall python`?

Comment: @Anthony I could use `pip3` after `brew reinstall python`, but I need to install the libraries like `numpy, pandas, ...` again. What can I do if I don't need to not install them again?

Comment: whenever you upgrade your operating system you usually need to reinstall all the things

Comment: I guess it is mainly about the site-packages path. Upgrading OS wouldn't have influenced the downloaded file stored on disk. If using Pycharm, it's ok to import the downloaded Python3 libraries, but when using Jupiter notebook, it fails to load the libraries in previous path.

Comment: it definitely could, the system libraries they link against could have changed or moved